# How to center align the image with reRestructuredText?

Tags: html, css, alignment, restructuredtext

[This post](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) says the following directive is a way to align image.

```
.. image:: ./imgs/code.jpg
    :width: 400px
    :align: center
```

However, the image is not center aligned, but right aligned, and I see the HTML generated as follows.

```
<img alt="./imgs/code.jpg" class="align-center" src="./imgs/code.jpg" style="width: 400px;" />
```

It's defined in as the align-center class contrary to the explanation : "The alignment of the image, equivalent to the HTML  tag's "align" attribute."

I even tried to have the CSS.

```
.. raw:: html

    <style type="text/css">
      .align-center {
         text-align: center;
         border: 0px;
      }
    </style>
```

And it also doesn't work.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Did you cleared the float `float:none;`? or try `margin: 0px auto;` .

Comment: The linked documentation is updated to reflect the changed implementation in HTML5. Further improvement suggestions are welcome. In Doctuils' HTML output, the `<image>` element is by default a block element (as set by the default style sheet) and the "text-align" CSS property does not work. The solution ("auto" margins) is already suggested in the answers below.

Answer (score 6):

According to this site: [docutils](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html) you can use a specific directive like the following:

```
.. image:: picture.jpeg
   :align: center
```

Answer (score 2):

As well as setting the `:align: center` flag, add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
img.align-center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try   `margin:0px auto;`

If this doesn't work for you, it means there are other styling causing this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following hack to align the image in the center

```
.. raw:: html
   <h1 align="center">
   <a href="your href link"><img width="200" src="image link" alt="text"></a>
   </h1>
```